# Adding Datarow between Rows?

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

how can i add rows between existing rows in a datatable ? 
Thanks

Comment: you mean in the middle? not appending!!? if yes, so why?

Comment: yes in the middle. I calculate some data and then they must add in the middle

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[*dataTable*.Rows.InsertAt(DataRow row, int position)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.insertat.aspx);

---

Sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static DataTable getDataTable()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("userID", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("userName", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("isAwesome", typeof(bool));
            return table;
        }

        static DataRow getRow(DataTable table, int userID, string userName, bool isAwesome)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["userID"] = userID;
            row["userName"] = userName;
            row["isAwesome"] = isAwesome;
            return row;
        }

        static void printTable(DataTable table)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (object val in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}, ", val);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable table = getDataTable();
            table.Rows.Add(getRow(table, 1, "Juliet", true));
            table.Rows.Add(getRow(table, 2, "Sean Hannity", false));
            table.Rows.Add(getRow(table, 3, "Charles Darwin", true));

            Console.WriteLine("Before:");
            printTable(table);

            // adding a row at index 1, between me and Sean Hannity
            Console.WriteLine("------------\nAfter:");
            DataRow barackRow = getRow(table, 4, "Barack Obama", true);
            table.Rows.InsertAt(barackRow, 1);
            printTable(table);

            Console.Write("Press any key. . .");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Juliet! please you can make a sample. it will be fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sample:

```
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("a", typeof(int));

            DataRow r = table.NewRow();
            r[0] = 10;
            table.Rows.Add(r);

            r = table.NewRow();
            r[0] = 12;
            table.Rows.InsertAt(r, 0);
```